# How to Pass A list of Dataframes Through a Loop

Tags: r, dataframe, list, loops

I have a list of annual animal tracking datasets that I'm trying to calculate home range estimates for. I have a loop that will calculate home range estimates for each annual dataset, but what I'd like to do is be able to feed both annual datasets through the loop and get MCP objects for each dataframe.

Here's an example of my code so far using buffalo data built into the ctmm package. The first chunk is just to read in and get the data properly formatted. No need to troubleshoot this section, its just necessary to get the data ready for the home range loop.

```
library(ctmm) 
library(ggplot2) 
library(dplyr) 
library(stringr) 
library(lubridate) 
library(sf) 
library(tidyverse) 
library(sp) 
library(scales) 
library(tidyr) 
library(tibble)

###########DATA CLEANING STEPS (Already works, no need to focus on)#################################
#Load the data
data("buffalo")

#Creating individual dataframes and adding an id column
Cilla <- as.data.frame(buffalo$Cilla) 
Cilla$id<-"Cilla"

Gabs<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Gabs)
Gabs$id<-"Gabs"

Mvubu<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Mvubu)
Mvubu$id<-"Mvubu"

Pepper<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Pepper)
Pepper$id<-"Pepper"

Queen<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Queen)
Queen$id<-"Queen"

Toni<-as.data.frame(buffalo$Toni)
Toni$id<-"Toni"

#Combining dataframes and adding a year, UTM zone, and date column
buffalo2 <- rbind(Cilla,Gabs,Mvubu,Pepper,Queen,Toni)
buffalo2$Year<-year(buffalo2$timestamp)
buffalo2$Year<-as.factor(buffalo2$Year)
buffalo2$UTM.zone<-"12 +datum=NAD27"
buffalo2$timestamp <- ymd_hms(buffalo2$timestamp) 
buffalo2$Timestamp<-buffalo2$timestamp
buffalo2 <- separate(buffalo2, timestamp, c("date","time"), sep= " ", remove= TRUE, extra= "merge")

#Reordering columns
buffalo2 <- buffalo2[, c(8,9,1,2,6,7,11,10)]

#Splitting data by year
data2005<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2005)
data2006<-buffalo2 %>% 
  filter(Year==2006)

#Creating annual telemetry data
Tdata2005<-as.telemetry(data2005, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
                        timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                        na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)
Tdata2006<-as.telemetry(data2006, timeformat="auto",timezone="UTC", 
                        timeout=Inf,datum="NAD27",
                        na.rm="row",mark.rm=FALSE,keep=FALSE,drop=FALSE)

#Creating a list of telemetry data
Tdata<-list(Tdata2005,Tdata2006)
names(Tdata)<-c("Tdata2005","Tdata2006")
```

Here's my loop that is able to calculate MCP home range estimates for a single annual dataframe (ex: Tdata2005).

```
#Load adehabitat package
library(adehabitatHR)

#buffalo MCP loop
buffalo.sp<-list()
MCP<-list()
for(i in 1:length(Tdata2005)){
  X<-Tdata2005[[i]][[5]]
  Y<-Tdata2005[[i]][[6]]
  ID<-names(Tdata2005)
  XY <- data.frame(X, Y)
  buffalo.sp[[i]]<-data.frame(ID[[i]],X,Y)
  coordinates(buffalo.sp[[i]]) <- c('X', 'Y')
  MCP[[i]]<-mcp(buffalo.sp[[i]], percent=95)
  plot(buffalo.sp[[i]], col=as.factor(buffalo.sp[[i]]@data$ID),pch=16,main=paste("MCP_",names((Tdata2005[i]))),axes=TRUE)+
    plot(MCP[[i]], col=alpha(1:13,0.5),add=TRUE)
}
names(buffalo.sp)<-names(Tdata2005)
names(MCP)<-names(Tdata2005)
```

What I'd like to do now is figure out how to run the entire list of dataframes (Tdata) through the loop (maybe a function that include the loop?) to get MCP estimates for all individuals in both annual dataframes (Tdata2005 and Tdata2006). Any ideas how I could go about doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to wrap the code in a function and then loop over the `list` and apply the function

```
library(adehabitatHR)
f1 <- function(tdata)
{
buffalo.sp<-list()
MCP<-list()
for(i in 1:length(tdata)){
  X<-tdata[[i]][[5]]
  Y<-tdata[[i]][[6]]
  ID<-names(tdata)
  XY <- data.frame(X, Y)
  buffalo.sp[[i]]<-data.frame(ID[[i]],X,Y)
  coordinates(buffalo.sp[[i]]) <- c('X', 'Y')
  MCP[[i]]<-mcp(buffalo.sp[[i]], percent=95)
  plot(buffalo.sp[[i]], col=as.factor(buffalo.sp[[i]]@data$ID),
    pch=16,main=paste("MCP_",names((Tdata2005[i]))),axes=TRUE)+
    plot(MCP[[i]], col=alpha(1:13,0.5),add=TRUE)
}
names(buffalo.sp)<-names(tdata)
names(MCP)<-names(tdata)
return(list(buffalo.sp = buffalo.sp, MCP = MCP))


}

out <- vector('list', length(Tdata))
 for(i in seq_along(out)) out[[i]] <- f1(Tdata[[i]])
```

-output

```
> str(out)
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ buffalo.sp:List of 5
  .. ..$ Cilla:Formal class 'SpatialPointsDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 5 slots
  .. .. .. ..@ data       :'data.frame':    3527 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. .. .. .. ..$ ID..i..: chr [1:3527] "Cilla" "Cilla" "Cilla" "Cilla" ...
  .. .. .. ..@ coords.nrs : int [1:2] 2 3
  .. .. .. ..@ coords     : num [1:3527, 1:2] 29080 25856 26454 27045 26350 ...
...
```